# I am writing a program that counts how often each word occurs in the given string

Tags: python

When I run this program nothing prints out. Since this is my first time working with dictionaries, I'm not sure how to debug it

```
str = "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of 
wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, 
it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, 
it was the winter of despair" 

#split the str into a list of separate words 
strL = str.lower()
strLst = strL.split()
#print(strLst)

#create dictionar
myDiction = {}

#use for in loop to traverse the list and add the keys/frequency
for key in myDiction:  
   #if the key is already in list, then increase frequency
   if key in myDiction: 
      myDiction[key] += 1
   #else create a key and add one to its frequency
   else: 
      myDiction[key] = 1
      
#print it 
for key in myDiction: 
   print(key, myDiction[key])
```

Comment: The first loop should be `for key in strLst:`, not `for key in myDiction:`

Comment: This code is not syntactically valid. It looks like the value for `str` has been accidentally split across multiple lines.

Comment: Please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and making a [mre]. Often, just the process of making an MRE will help you catch typos / basic mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
for key in myDiction:
```

You're not running through `strLst` in your for loop.  You're running through `myDiction`--the **empty** dictionary you just made.

Swap `strLst` in for `myDiction` in that line and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at line `for key in myDiction:`, as you are iterating over `myDiction` (which is an empty dictionary), so `for loop` is not working.
Try to replace `myDiction` with `strLst` to iterate on the actual list of strings.

Additionally, I would recommend the following improvements:

1. At line 1, you are creating a variable named `str = "your string"`, `str` is reserved keyword in Python, so try not to use it, you can instead use `my_string`, or something different.
2. For longer strings, you can use multiline quotations like `str = """very long string"""`
3. Rename `myDiction` to what actually its storing, i.e. something like `counter={}`.
4. Instead of doing `myDiction[key] = 1` at line 21, you can use default dict to ease this overhead to initialize first count with 1.
5. You can use `collections.Counter` to do the same.

**Here's the final code (if you want to stick with your code)**:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_string = """It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of 
wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, 
it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, 
it was the winter of despair""" 

#split the str into a list of separate words 
lower_case = my_string.lower()
words = lower_case.split()
#print(strLst)

#create counter dict
counter = defaultdict(int)

#use for in loop to traverse the list and add the keys/frequency
for word in words:
    counter[word] += 1
      
#print it 
for key, value in counter.items(): 
   print(key, value)
```

**Here's more appropriate one, if we use built-in Counter**:

```
from collections import Counter

my_string = """It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of 
wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, 
it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, 
it was the winter of despair""" 

#split the str into a list of separate words 
lower_case = my_string.lower()
words = lower_case.split()
#print(strLst)

# builtin counter
counter = Counter(words)

#print it 
for key, value in counter.items(): 
   print(key, value)
```